# c# loop with httpclientconnection

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, ssis

I'm trying to run a number of SSRS reports via an SSIS package written in C# using a loop.  The problem is that the below code only produces 1 file based on the initial parameters pass through.  I think the problem is the ConnectionManager and HttpClientConnection being reused.  Is there some other way of doing this?

```
        for (int i = 0; i <= cust.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            string varDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            string d1ThisMOnth = System.DateTime.Today.AddDays(-(DateTime.Today.Day - 1)).ToString();
            var today = DateTime.Today;
            var month = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
            var first = month.AddMonths(-1);
            var last = month.AddDays(-1);
            string reportfilename = @"D:\Reports\AllActiveAccounts_" + month.ToString("MMyyyy") + "_" + cust[0, 0] + "." + cust[0, 4];
            string url = @"http://" + cust[i, 5] + "/ReportServer?/" + cust[i, 0] + "/Report&rs:Command=Render&location=" + cust[i, 1] + "&clityp=" + cust[i, 2] + "&acctyp=" + cust[i, 3] + "&startdate=" + first.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "&enddate=" + last.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "&rs:Format=" + cust[i, 4] + "&rc:Toolbar=False";
            ConnectionManager httpConn = Dts.Connections["ReportServer"];
            HttpClientConnection clientConn = new HttpClientConnection(httpConn.AcquireConnection(null));
            clientConn.ServerURL = url;
            clientConn.DownloadFile(reportfilename, true);
        }
```

Comment: Is `cust[0, 0] + "." + cust[0, 4];` supposed to be `cust[i, 0] + "." + cust[i, 4];` on the line where `reportfilename` is assigned?

Comment: As to whether there is another way of doing this, yes. The specifics of it would involve a For Loop to handle the looping logic, SSIS level Variables with Expression applied to build out your report name and url. Those two variables would be passed to your script task which would be distilled to your last 4 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a guess, but if I were to. I'd say it's because you're not using your loop counter in your reportfilename parameter. Try changing the filename line to the below.

```
string reportfilename = @"D:\Reports\AllActiveAccounts_" + month.ToString("MMyyyy") + "_" + cust[i, 0] + "." + cust[i, 4];
```